# Sort Array of Arrays by length with tiebreaker

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting

I have an `Array` of `Array`s that I want to sort by longest length to shortest.  I achieved this easily enough with a `sort_by`

```
> a =  [ [1, 2, 9],
         [4, 5, 6, 7],
         [1, 2, 3] ]
> a.sort_by(&:length).reverse # or a.sort_by {|e| e.length}.reverse
=> [[4, 5, 6, 7], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 9]]
```

What I want, however is to have a sort of tie-breaker for lists of equal length.  If two lists' lengths are equal, the list whose **last entry is greater** should come first.    So in the above, `[1, 2, 9]` and `[1, 2, 3]` should be switched.

I don't care abouth the case where two lists have both equal length and equal last element, they can be in whatever order if that occurs.  I don't know if/how I can acheive this with ruby built-in sorting.

Comment: Use a block, like in the example in the docs: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can still do this with [`sort_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by), you just need to realize that [Ruby arrays compare element-by-element](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E):

> **ary <=> other_ary → -1, 0, +1 or nil**
>
> [...]
>
> Each object in each array is compared (using the <=> operator).
>
> Arrays are compared in an “element-wise” manner; the first two elements that are not equal will determine the return value for the whole comparison.

That means that you can use arrays as the `sort_by` key, then throw in a bit of integer negation to reverse the sort order and you get:

```
a.sort_by { |e| [-e.length, -e.last] }
```

That will give you the `[[4, 5, 6, 7], [1, 2, 9], [1, 2, 3]]` that you're looking for.

If you're not using numbers so the "negation to reverse the order" trick won't work, then use [Shaunak's `sort`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18264780/479863) approach.

Comment: Excellent answer, though it may seem ordinary to fluent Rubyists.

Comment: @BorisStitnicky: Thanks. I actually see that as an SQL inspired solution, that's pretty much a straight transliteration of `order by length desc, last desc` (except the SQL version would work equally well with strings since it doesn't depend on the "negation reverses the order" trick).

Comment: Excellent answer @muistooshort. Out of curiosity, is there a computational difference between how your solution will compare against mine? especially if the arrays are too big and complex? I am not sure how sory_by executes its block will it sort twice or like in my solution it just modifies the comparison in the same go.

Comment: @Shaunak: `sort_by` does a [Schwartzian Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) so the block will be executed once per array element. The difference isn't worth worrying about for small arrays; for large arrays, you'd need to weight the expense of the block's computation against the memory overhead of the memorization.

Comment: Thanks! That helps. Downside of using ruby sugar is we tend overlook these things.

Answer (score 3):

There you go :

```
a =  [ [1, 2, 9],[4, 5, 6, 7],[1, 2, 3] ]
a.sort { |a, b| (b.count <=> a.count) == 0 ? (b.last <=> a.last): (b.count <=> a.count)  }
```

That should give you:

```
[[4, 5, 6, 7], [1, 2, 9], [1, 2, 3]]
```

How this works: we pass a block to sort function, which first checks if the array length is same, if not it continues to check for last element.

Comment: I think `(a.length == b.length)` for the first condition would better match your explanation `if the array length is same`.

Comment: All I'm, suggesting is: `(a.length == b.length) ?` instead of `(b.count <=> a.count) == 0 ?`

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
a.sort_by {|i| [i.length, i.last] }.reverse
# => [[4, 5, 6, 7], [1, 2, 9], [1, 2, 3]]
```